# How to fix "Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified." error in unity

Tags: c#

Literally started to learn to code a few days ago just been watching videos but when i try and add a script for player movement on my object there in an error

This is on unity engine and i haven't tried much yet because i don't know where to start

> Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx
>   (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) (at
>   <735c83e43c004ee998f77c68cf8035da>:0) System.Diagnostics.Process.Start
>   () (at <735c83e43c004ee998f77c68cf8035da>:0) (wrapper
>   remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
>   UnityEditor.DefaultExternalCodeEditor.OpenProject (System.String path,
>   System.Int32 line, System.Int32 column) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/CodeEditor/DefaultExternalCodeEditor.cs:136)
>   Unity.CodeEditor.CodeEditor.OpenProject (System.String path,
>   System.Int32 line, System.Int32 column) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/CodeEditor/CodeEditor.cs:31)

The code i put into visual studio is

```cs
    using UnityEngine;

    public class Playermovement : MonoBehaviour
    {
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Hello. world");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
    }
```

i was just expecting on the console to write "Hello. world"

Comment: https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-api-reference-error.201293/

Answer (score -1):

> There is no any method available like Log in Debug class.
>   You just use Write and WriteLine , Print etc.

```
Debug.Write("Hello. world");
```